# Return two types with NuSOAP

Tags: php, nusoap

I have a working webService using NuSOAP. Now, I have to make a validation before returning the data requested. If everything is ok, I return it normally, otherwise I would like to return a String message explaining why I'm not giving the information requested. Problem is that I can't get to add two different types of return to RegisterFunction of NuSOAP. If I add a ComplexType as return, I can't return a String.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.  What have you tried? What hasn't worked? What research have you done to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function can't have two return-values. You should add the error-message-string to your complex type. If you don't wanna touch your complex type, then you should create another
complex type wich contains your datatype and a string.

Example - the complex type you have right now:

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType('myData','complexType','struct','all','',
    array(  'important'  => array('name' => 'important','type' => 'xsd:string'),
            'stuff'      => array('name' => 'stuff','type' => 'xsd:string')
    )
);
```

the extra complex type:

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType('package','complexType','struct','all','',
    array(  'data'      => array('name' => 'data','type' => 'tns:myData'),
            'errormsg'  => array('name' => 'errormsg','type' => 'xsd:string')
    )
);
```

registration of the function:

```
$server->register(
                'getData',     
                array('validation'=>'xsd:string'), 
                array('return'=>'tns:package'),
                $namespace,
                false,
                'rpc',
                'encoded',
                'description'
);
```

the function:

```
function GetData($validation)
{
    if($validation == "thegoodguy") {
        $result['data'] = array(
            "important"    => "a top secret information",
            "stuff"        => "another one"
        );
        $result['errormsg'] = null;
    } else {
        $result['data'] = null;
        $result['errormsg'] = "permission denied!";
    }
    return $result;
}
```

That way the client could try to analyse the received data and if it is null then he
shows up the errormessage.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to define a new type that describes an array of strings like so:

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
  'ArrayOfString',
  'complexType',
  'array',
  'sequence',
  '',
  array(
    'itemName' => array(
      'name' => 'itemName', 
      'type' => 'xsd:string',
      'minOccurs' => '0', 
      'maxOccurs' => 'unbounded'
    )
  )
);
```

Then you can use tns:ArrayOfString as the return type.

Comment: That is not what I want to return. I want to return an Array of a odel which I already have the ComplexType of it, but I also wants to return a single String if by all means I can't return the ComplexType that was intended. It's like I want 2 types of return in a single function. 1 for success (ComplexType) and the other for failure (message)